# Numerically robust predicate for determining common sphere

Tags: package, computational-geometry, cgal, delaunay

I would like to know if there is any library/package which provides *numerically robust* predicate for testing whether n-points(in my case n=5) lie on a common sphere?

I want to perform this test in context of Delaunay tetrahedralization. I have seen packages in **CGAL** but cannot find any explicit function for this problem.

One approach that I can think of is using CGAL `CGAL::Sphere_d` class to initialize a sphere using 4 points and for all remaining points I will use `has_on_boundary()` function to test if all points lie on common sphere, but I am not sure if it can work in general, I mean is it *provably* correct to do common sphere test this way.

Comment: What dimension are you working in?

Comment: @sloriot Points are 3-dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either [`CGAL::side_of_bounded_sphere()`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/group__side__of__bounded__sphere__grp.html) or [`CGAL::side_of_oriented_sphere()`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/group__side__of__oriented__sphere__grp.html) with a kernel having exact predicates like [`CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Exact__predicates__inexact__constructions__kernel.html).

You can use it like this:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_3 Point_3;

int main()
{
   Point_3 p1(XX,XX,XX), p2(XX,XX,XX), p3(XX,XX,XX), p4(XX,XX,XX), p5(XX,XX,XX);
   if (CGAL::side_of_bounded_sphere(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5) == CGAL::ON_BOUNDARY)
     //the points are co-spherical
}
```

Comment: In my case I have 5 points to check for co-spherical condition. And my problem does not enforce any particular choice of the 4 points used to define the sphere, but can it affect the result of `CGAL::side_of_bounded_sphere()` or `CGAL::side_of_oriented_sphere()` if I use any arbitrary 4 points to define the sphere and the remaining as the test point?

Comment: of course you should read CGAL::side_of_bounded_sphere(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5) with 5 arguments

Comment: @olivier Actually, my comment is not about the mistake in the code(which I choose to ignore because Sebastien's response gave me the required hint anyway). I want to resolve my doubt that since in my problem there is no particular choice of 4 points to define the sphere I will have to arbitrarily select 4 points from the set of 5 points, can it affect the result of the predicate or it will behave _ideally_(i.e., independent of the choice of points defining the sphere)?

Comment: The 4 points can be arbitrarily chosen. Note that contrary to side_of_oriented_sphere,  side_of_bounded_sphere expects the 4 points to be non-coplanar. @Olivier:I fixed the code, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[There are robust 2D and 3D primitives](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html) for "incircle check" in Triangle triangulation package by J. Schewchuk

Answer (score 2):

What about converting all your points to integer coordinates, using suitable scaling.

The InSphere test is an expression of the fifth degree wrt the coordinates. Roughly speaking, using 64 bits arithmetic you can test spheres up to diameter 6,000 or so. With extended precision, 128 bits, you cover up to 44,000,000 (only +, -, * required).

The benefit is that you avoid any risk of algorithm failures arising from predicate incoherence.

Comment: "...InSphere test is an expression of the fifth degree wrt the coordinates...", I would like to understand this more clearly, would you please point me to some reference/paper on this topic.

Comment: Just have a look at the formula: http://theses.ulaval.ca/archimede/fichiers/25876/ch04.html#d0e1515

Comment: Ok I understood how Insphere test is fifth degree in terms of coordinates. I have 2 questions: 1. InSphere test involves only Matrix determinate computation so why do we need to try against spheres with different diameters(for which you report range on diameters for different precisions) ? 2. What is **predicate incoherence**?

Comment: I don't know why I am not able to notify you with @Yves Daoust. I am inserting it in my comments but it is not visible in the post.

Comment: "so why do we need to try against spheres with different diameters": this is not what I mean, I am just giving you the range of sizes that you can process without overflow

Comment: "predicate incoherence": due to numerical inaccuracies, the InSphere test can sometimes return true when it should say false, and conversely; with exact arithmetic this is avoided

Comment: Does that mean predicates by Schewchuck and those in CGAL also suffer from predicate incoherence?

Comment: No idea. If they are truly exact, they must use very high accuracy, like tenfold precision, which is overkill.